# How can I install ffmpeg to my docker image

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

I have setup a docker image in my Windows 10 Machine. 
Can you please tell me how can I install ffmpeg to that docker image?

Comment: can you share your dockerfile ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `dockerfile` you can write this command to add required repo, update your repository and then install `ffmpeg`.

Though I am not sure if this library still exist I just modified this [Link](https://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-ubuntu-14-04/) for Docker you can follow same rules to install another package.

```
RUN set -x \
    && add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get dist-upgrade \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ffmpeg \
```

Answer (score 38):

`apt-get install ffmpeg`

As of 2019, this seems to work, just fine on Docker.

Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

Comment: Getting ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Should AND the commands so the updates run if you change the ffmpeg line at some point: `RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y ffmpeg`

Answer (score 14):

As of July 2022, this works for Dockerfile, well at least it worked for me.

```py
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ffmpeg
```

Just to let the community know.

Answer (score 6):

If you stop with select of geographic area on Ubuntu 18.04 or above, you can install it by specifying `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` as shown below.

```dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg
```

Comment: This is the right response!
Thank you!

Comment: You should keep the DEBIAN_FRONTEND in the same line otherwise it will be persistent over the whole docker file. 

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

see here: (https://serverfault.com/questions/618994/when-building-from-dockerfile-debian-ubuntu-package-install-debconf-noninteract)

Comment: DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive should be immediately before the apt-get install though like this:
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y ffmpeg